# Reduce space between text and border?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web portal social media page. I want the text in the middle of the page to have a border around it relatively close to the text. However, whenever I add a border in my CSS it seems to border the entire page rather than the text. Is there anyway to reduce the amount of space in between my text and border?

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ben_buchanan {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 72px;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.fullstop {
  background: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class="ben_buchanan">BEN BUCHANAN<mark class="fullstop">.</mark></h1>
```

Here's how it currently looks:

[image]

Here is the [code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z3Y7mPGh).

Comment: Thank you to showdev also for editing the post. I am still new here so was unfamiliar with formatting my post. Many thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `border` applies to the entire "bounding box" of the element. Since you have specified a width and height for the element, the border will be around that area.

The solution would be to create an inline element *inside* the `.ben_buchanan` element, and this is the element that actually contains the text and the border.

So

```
<h1 class="ben_buchanan">BEN BUCHANAN<mark class="fullstop">.</mark></h1>
```

becomes

```
<h1 class="ben_buchanan">
    <span class="inside_text">BEN BUCHANAN<mark class="fullstop">.</mark></span>
</h1>
```

And you apply the border to `.inside_text`.

Answer (score 1):

You can first set your h1 style to be something like this:

```
<h1 style='border:2px black solid;'>BEN BUCHANAN<mark 
class="fullstop">.</mark></h1>
```

Then, set the display in css like:

```
h1{
   display:inline;
}
```

That should fix your problem with the border not wrapping around the text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the border to H1 div, which takes up 90% height of your page. So a border around that would appear at the edge of the screen- Not around your text.

In your case, you can have a wrapper div around your H1 tag which should have `display:flex` and height defined to it. Then use `vertical-align: middle;` to makes all inner content elements to be vertically centered.

H1 has display block that will allow it to take entire screen width. So to have your border right near the left and right of the content.
Make your H1 as `display:inline-block` so that vertical align will have its effects on it. And apply `margin:0 auto` that should make the text horizontally centered.

So your text will be finally center aligned in the page (vertical & horizontal) with the border around it.

You can increase the space around border and the text, by applying padding to the h1.

Check out the below snippet

```css
/* General */

html, body {
 background-color: #000000;
 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 
 overflow: hidden; /* Will hide anything on the x and y axis that goes outside of the element, so there would be no need for a scrollbar */
}

/* Classes */
.name-wrapper{
  align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 90%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.ben_buchanan {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.fullstop {
 background: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 
 -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Animations */

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
 0% { 
  opacity: 0;
 }
 50% { 
  opacity: 1.0;
 }
 100% { 
 opacity: 0;
 }
}

/* Miscellaneous */

.disable_text_highlighting {
 -webkit-user-select: none; 
 -moz-user-select: none;   
 -ms-user-select: none;  
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="disable_text_highlighting">

 <style type="text/css"></style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="favicon" href="favicon.ico"/>

 <head>
  <title>Ben Buchanan</title>
 </head>

 <body>
      <div class="name-wrapper">
  <h1 class="ben_buchanan">BEN BUCHANAN<mark class="fullstop">.</mark></h1>
        <div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply!

Comment: @BenBuchanan Now the element will align to middle of the page. Check out the snippet